# How to switch bitcoin to ether in coinbase

Tags: wallets, exchanges, coinbase

I have btc in coinbase, how do I switch some of it to ethers? I don't have a bank account attached to it, and don't want to. I tried the coinbase information, but it says I have to attach a bank account.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open a Jaxx Wallet and send your bitcoin there and you can switch to ethereum there

Answer (score 3):

You can go to gdax.com (the exchange portion of coinbase), and from there you are able to deposit your BTC that is currently in your Coinbase account. From there, simply make the exchange on the ETH-BTC market.  You can then withdrawal the ETH back into your Coinbase account.

Comment: Is it required to do KYC via bank account verification in gdax? I believe the OP might have some problem with that as well.

Comment: Yes I believe so. It is my understanding that Coinbase and GDAX verification standards are synonymous.

Comment: Thanks but I didn't like all the questions gdax asked . So I opened a Jaxx wallet and moved bit coin there, that let's you switch it to etherereum

Comment: Using GDAX, it doesn't look like there's a way to go directly from BTC to ETH without turning the BTC into dollars first.. So this answer's not very good I'm afraid

Comment: Turns out, you actually can do as described, the interface is just a little confusing how it says "Total:"

Answer (score 3):

The simplest method would be to set up a [local currency wallet on Coinbase](https://support.coinbase.com/customer/portal/articles/1780543-how-do-i-use-my-local-currency-wallet-usd-eur-gbp-), and sell your BTC to that wallet. Then, you can use the funds from that wallet to purchase ETH.

Comment: Simply having a coinbase wallet won't let you do this. am I missing something?

Comment: @Amalgovinus There are two requirements listed [here](https://support.coinbase.com/customer/portal/articles/1780543-how-do-i-use-my-local-currency-wallet-usd-eur-gbp-#states%20and%20countries) : "In order to activate your local currency wallet, you must:
Reside in a supported state or country.
Upload an identification document issued in your state or country of residence."

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ShapeShift](https://shapeshift.io), but the fees might be higher than using a fiat wallet as [arseniy](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/15769/1562) suggested.